# Record not getting updated in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change some values in a table but for some reason the values are not getting updated. Here is the php :

```
$title=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title']);
echo $title."<br>"; //Test
$note=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['jnote']);
echo $note."<br>"; //Test



$query="UPDATE articles SET return_j='1' AND j_note='$note' WHERE article_name='$title'";
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Problem is I am getting no error. 'Record updated successfully' is what I get. So the query is being executed successfully but the table is not getting updated. I don't understand why.

When I am updating other columns of the table (in some other scripts), I am having no problem.

Comment: `SET return_j='1' AND j_note='$note'` - is that legal?

Comment: Might be. Thanks. Let me see

Comment: RTM on UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html something you did not do.

Comment: Plus, your record on accepting answers is to speak of. Start accepting answers for solutions given and remain in good standing in the community.

Comment: your silence isn't helping anyone here unless you left the question, to which I have done myself. Voted to close as a typo, being "off-topic".

Comment: Not illegal. Just wrong.

Comment: I am sorry. I couldn't login for many days. This was actually just that I had mistakenly used AND instead of a comma as pointed out by everyone. I just didn't notice the mistake. I am just not able to close the question as it has answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap out the AND for a comma.

```
UPDATE articles SET return_j='1', j_note='$note' WHERE article_name='$title'
```

and I don't think you need

```
===TRUE
```

just leave it out of the condition statement.

Comment: True. A sidenote: It's also best to use `mysqli_affected_rows()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php with UPDATE. That way they get actual truthness.

Comment: I'd take a look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317051/record-not-getting-updated-in-php-mysql#comment71787739_42317051) I left under their question though. That could swing either way.